# How do I change validation text in jQuery DatePicker in MVC 4?

Tags: jquery, validation, datepicker, overriding, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 project and am not satisfied with the default error text displayed after validating the date in the date picker. Is there a way to override this? My razor code looks like this: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstimatedDeliveryDate)`

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by DataAnnotation in model.

If you are using Required attribute:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must give an estimated delivery date")]
public string EstimatedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy, the jQuery datepicker is still taking over on validation.